# Bookmark manager for Windows and Android

Tags: windows, android, bookmark

For years, I have been using [Linkman](https://www.outertech.com/en/bookmark-manager) and consider it money well spent.

At the time, I did a lot of searching, and it was the best there was, but that was many years ago & who knows what has appeared since?

I am looking for something similar, but which runs on both Windows and Android (with the idea being to have a single, shared, database and synch it with DropBox).

At the very least, a tree hierarchy, like the Windows explorer, where I can create "folders" and sub-folder, plus search capabilities.

Whatever you recommend must be able to import my extensive collection of bookmarks which Linkman can export in the formats listed on   [this page](https://www.outertech.com/help_linkman/index.html?importexport.htm)

Preferably gratis, maybe up to $25-ish

---

[Update] Sorry, I should have been more explicit; I want an app, not browser synching of bookmarks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Raindrop](https://raindrop.io). It runs on Windows as a browser extension and has an Android and iOS app. It supports nested folders, but that is a premium feature. You can import your linkman bookmarks as HTML.